# Tomcat 9 no responde en puerto 80

Tags: tomcat

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web con Spring y quiero probarla en un servidor tomcat 9. Abrí el puerto 80 en el router y desvié todo todo el tráfico a la IP del portátil, donde tengo instalado el servidor. Configuré el servidor para aceptar peticiones en el puerto 80 y el atributo address del Connector con valor "0.0.0.0" para aceptar peticiones desde todas las IPs. Al desplegar la aplicación todo funciona bien y el servidor responde al localhost y la IP publica desde distintos dispositivos conectados a la misma Red y por 4G. 
Compre un dominio en DonDominio e instalé el DonDns para apuntar el dominio a mí IP(dinámica), y es cuando tomcat dejó de responder al puerto 80(sólo respondía al localhost).Sin embargo si cambiaba la configuración de tomcat al puerto 81 y abría ese puerto en el router si respondía desde la IP pública.
Mire los servicios de Windows y el cortafuegos. Nada usaba el puerto 80. 
Que podría estar bloqueando al servidor para que no acepte las peticiones en el puerto 80, pero si en el 81?
Un saludo

Comment: Saludos Boris, te recomiendo colocar la respuesta en la parte de respuestas (abajo de la pregunta). Gracias por mantener el orden en el sitio :D

Comment: revertí tu edición, pues como te comentan la pregunta va en la parte superior y la solución en la parte de abajo, saludos

Comment: Gracias por la corrección.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado!
Parece ser que al redirigir el puerto 80 en el router lo hace sobre la LAN y yo estaba conectado por WiFi. Me resulta extraño pero funciona.